# Print Integers in a Pyramid

Tags: java, console, formatting, complexity

I need to write a method that will print the integers from `[1, maxValue]` in a pyramid where the `nth` row contains `n` numbers like so (for `printChart(24)`):

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 
22 23 24
```

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize my code for functionality, simplicity, or computational complexity (although I doubt the latter, because I think this runs at \$O(n)\$ time).

It has one helper function, which returns a boolean value representing whether or not a given integer, `n`, is a perfect square.

```
public boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
    int root = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    return root * root == n;
}

public void printChart(int maxValue) {
    int number = 1;
    while (number <= maxValue) {

        System.out.print(number + " ");

        /* A number n can be determined to be triangular iff
         8n+1 is a perfect square;  if n is a triangular number,
         print a line after it*/
        if(isPerfectSquare(8*number+1)) { System.out.println(); }

        number++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example is misleading, the sixth row contains 9 numbers.

Comment: Hello, I executed your code, and numbers 22, 23, 24 appear below the last row that ends with number 21.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing things quite the hard way. You don't need to call `sqrt`, or determine perfect squares at all. Simply track `y`, and as soon as the row's `x` == `y`, make a newline, increment `y` and set `x` = 0.

The following examples show different results from what you've described:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.lang.Math;

class Pyramid {
    interface ChartMethod {
        abstract void run(int n);
    }

    static boolean isPerfectSquare(int n){
        int root = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
        return root * root == n;
    }

    static void chart_squares(int maxValue) {
        int number = 1;
        while (number <= maxValue) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");

            /* A number n can be determined to be triangular iff
             8n+1 is a perfect square;  if n is a triangular number,
             print a line after it*/
            if (isPerfectSquare(8*number + 1))
                System.out.println();
            number++;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    static void chart_coords(int maxValue) {
        int number = 1, y = 0, x = 0;
        while (number <= maxValue) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");

            if (x == y) {
                x = 0;
                y++;
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
                x++;

            number++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void chart_coordloop(int maxValue) {
        int number = 1;
        for (int y = 0;; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
                System.out.print(number + " ");
                if (number++ >= maxValue) {
                    System.out.println();
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static void chart_incr(int maxValue) {
        int increment = 2, next = 1;
        for (int number = 1; number <= maxValue; number++) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
            if (number == next) {
                next += increment;
                increment++;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void chart_buf(int maxValue) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        int increment = 2, next = 1;
        for (int number = 1; number <= maxValue; number++) {
            sw.write(number + " ");
            if (number == next) {
                next += increment;
                increment++;
                sw.write('\n');
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }

    static final ChartMethod[] methods = new ChartMethod[] {
        Pyramid::chart_squares,
        Pyramid::chart_coords,
        Pyramid::chart_coordloop,
        Pyramid::chart_incr,
        Pyramid::chart_buf
    };

    static void test(ChartMethod method) {
        method.run(7);
    }

    static void time(ChartMethod method) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        final int N = 200000;
        method.run(N);
        long dur = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.err.println(String.format("%.3f us", dur / 1e3 / N));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (ChartMethod method: methods)
            time(method);
    }
}
```

This shows:

```
1.381 us
1.196 us
1.157 us
1.140 us
0.234 us
```

The most important thing is to buffer the output before writing.

Comment: As I understand it, that does not work here. Could you possibly show an example code so I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: Edited. The only potential edge case is if the maximum number produces what would be a smaller row at the bottom. If, as your illustration shows, you need the bottom row to always be the widest, you'll need to add another clause to that `if`.

Comment: actually still works in the edge case you mentioned. Weirdly enough, my slightly more complex method (which I would expect to take longer to run?) tends to take around .3 seconds fewer to perform the same 1000 operations than your method. Any idea why?

Comment: Tough to say. `sqrt` might be using a highly-efficient processor instruction that takes less time than the additional complexity of having more variables in the loop that are affected by conditional logic.

Comment: I wrote an alternate implementation; I'd be interested to hear how it compares

Comment: I actually had an implementation very similar to this previously, and aside from being slightly more difficult to read, it was not as efficient (around .6 seconds slower for 1000 operations). Not the same implementation though, so this could be an improvement?

Comment: So in my test, `sqrt` came out last.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how using roots help you, but here is my solution to the porblem (a pyramid, n-th row has length of n):

EDIT: I assumed that if the number won't be a perfect pyramid (like 24) then print until the number. If you want to print the biggest pyramid possible it simplifies the code a bit.

```
public static String pyr(int n) { //n is the target num
    String str = "";
    int currNum = 1;
    int rowLength = 1;
    while (currNum <= n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {
            if (currNum <= n) { 
            //we want to go until n (not the end of this line)
                System.out.print(currNum + " ");
                currNum++;
            }
        }
        rowLength++;
        System.out.println();
    }
    return str;
}
```